“Princes shall come out of Egypt; Ethiopia shall soon stretch out her hands unto God.” — Psalms 68:31 (KJV)
Is it Ethiopia who's mentioned in the bible the same as today's Ethiopia ?

hi Ulfina welcome to BH_SC. This question might be more about ancient geography than the bible itself. From a quick look it's probably fairly safe to place Ethiopia between the Nile and the Red Sea - since those landmarks won't have moved since the ancient descriptions in e.g. Strabo - but the history of geography is a whole field of study in itself.

The Bible uses this name to describe several regions, some of which are quite unlike today's Ethiopia. The Jewish Encyclopedia states that in the Bible, Ethiopia is:

a name covering three different countries and peoples, viz.: (1)
Ethiopia proper; (2) parts of northern Arabia; and (3) the regions
east of Babylonia.

For our purposes, we may omit the Babylonian "Cush" which has to with very distant origins.
Psalm 68

29Because of Your temple at Jerusalem kings will bring You gifts.
30Rebuke the beast in the reeds,
the herd of bulls among the calves of the nations,
until it submits, bringing bars of silver.
Scatter the nations who delight in war.
31Envoys will arrive from Egypt; Ethiopia (Cush) will stretch out her hands to God.

In Psalm 68, the poet presents Ethiopia (called Cush in Hebrew) as a parallel to Egypt, implying a symmetry. Here, Cush is the southern region of Egypt. However, the Cushite people seem to have occupied the Sinai region as well.
See also this article


The two place-names in Ps 68:31 are:

מִצְרַיִם (Mitsrayim) = Son of Ham and the country he founded, Egypt in  English, Gen 10:6, 13, 12;10, 11, etc.
כּוּשׁ (kush) = a son a Ham and the country of the southern Nile Valley.

Here is a quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aethiopia -

The Greek name Aithiopia (Αἰθιοπία, from Αἰθίοψ, Aithíops, 'an
Ethiopian') is a compound derived of two Greek words: αἴθω, aíthō, 'I
burn' + ὤψ, ṓps, 'face'. According to the Perseus Project, this
designation properly translates in noun form as burnt-face and in
adjectival form as red-brown. As such, it was used as a vague term for
darker skinned populations than the Greeks since the time of Homer.
The term was applied to such peoples within the range of observation
of the ancient geographers, primarily in what was then Nubia (in
ancient Sudan). With the expansion of geographical knowledge, the
exonym successively extended to certain other areas below the Sahara.
In classical antiquity, the term Africa did not refer to any part of
sub-Saharan Africa, but in its widest sense to instead to Ancient
Libya—what is now known as the Maghreb and the desert to the south.

Thus, what we now call Ethiopia is within an area that was far more vaguely defined in ancient times.  Ancient Aethiopia included much more than the area of modern Ethiopia such as Sudan, etc.
